# Scala: merging two JSON files using AmazonS3Client getObject Futures

Tags: json, scala, amazon-s3

I'm trying to merge two JSON files from an S3 bucket.  First file pulls fine, but not the second file.

```
val eventLogJsonFuture = Future(new AmazonS3Client(credentials))
  .map(_.getObject(logBucket, logDirectory + "/" + id + "/event_log.json"))
  .map(_.getObjectContent)
  .map(Source.fromInputStream(_))
  .map(_.mkString)
  .map(Json.parse) map { archiveEvents =>

    Json.toJson(Json.obj("success" -> true, "data" -> archiveEvents))

  } recover {
    case NonFatal(error) =>
      Json.obj("success" -> false, "errorCode" -> "archive_does_not_exist", "message" -> error.getMessage)
  }


val infoJsonFuture = Future(new AmazonS3Client(credentials))
  .map(_.getObject(logBucket, logDirectory + "/" + id + "/info.json"))
  .map(_.getObjectContent)
  .map(Source.fromInputStream(_))
  .map(_.mkString)
  .map(Json.parse) map { archiveInfo =>

  Json.toJson(Json.obj("success" -> true, "data" -> archiveInfo))

} recover {
  case NonFatal(error) =>
    Json.obj("success" -> false, "errorCode" -> "archive_does_not_exist", "message" -> error.getMessage)
}

val combinedJson = for {
  eventLogJson <- eventLogJsonFuture
  infoJson <- infoJsonFuture
}
yield {
  Json.obj("info" -> infoJson, "events" -> eventLogJson)
}
```

This is what the result JSON looks like ...

[image: this is the json result]

Is there another (better?) way of writing this?

Comment: What's wrong with how you're doing it now? Looks elegant.

Comment: The problem is that infoJsonFuture is throwing a NonFatal error ... "Input length = 1" when the file really does exist on S3.  Could it be AmazonS3Client might not be able to run asynchronously on two separate threads?

Comment: Should you wait 3 parts of JSON from different source ?

Comment: "might not be able to run asynchronously on two separate threads" - it's easy for you to verify. Just add, e.g. `implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor)` before the futures and see if it works now.

Comment: @MichaelGorham Have you been able to parse the info.json file by itself? I wonder if there's an actual issue with the file.

Answer (score 0):

Should you wait 3 parts of JSON from different source ?

I can recommend solution with `case class DTO`

Simple example:

```
val firstJson = Future {
         //case class json1(...)
    }

    val secondJson = Future {
   //case class json2(...)
      ...
    }

    val finalFson = for {
      f <- first
      s <- second
    } yield (f, s)

finalJson onComplete {
      case Success(jsons) => {
        //merge json here
        jsons._1 + jsons._2 ... 

      }
```